# How to open a URL in incognito mode from .html file

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am trying to open an html link using target attribute in anchor tag. I can't seem to find a solution for it. Help needed!!

I tried all available option in target attribute but it does not solve my problem. Is window function my last resort or it can be done through html itself?!

Comment: This is possible with windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true}); see docs here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create#parameters